# MVC Image Handling - Can I make all images appear roughly the same?

Tags: css, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an MVC 4 app that includes the ability for users to upload images. I then display some of those images in another view. I allow the user to upload images with a maximum size of 10MB. I then use `WebImage (System.Web.Helpers)` to resize to image 800 x ?, keeping the same aspect ratio, and then save it to my DB.

When I display these images in my view, they are all shapes and sizes because of the way they were originally taken, despite my resizing to 800 x ?. Is there a way I can display these pictures so they appear to all have the same width and height, without some of the images appearing grossly distorted?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of how they are being displayed? Is it a grid of sorts with fixed width/height and the images get stretched within the cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can try to tackle this. You can try styling the image container with `overflow:hidden;`, and not limit the image's height (in case you are doing it - I suspect that could be the reason it stretches).

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div class="main">
   <img class="absolute" src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width:300px;
}

img.absolute{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/SQbBV/)

Alternatively, you could look into CSS masks. Here is a tutorial on various type of masks in CSS: [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/).

Comment: If I don't limit the image width and height, why would I need to style it with overflow:hidden?

Comment: I assume you are displaying it in some sort of grid and want things to align, thus limiting the height and creating stretching? Like I stated earlier, a screenshot of the problem would be helpful.